# how to get IEditorReference in eclipse 4.2

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have the follwoing code that is working in eclipse 3.7:

```
private static IEditorReference getReference(IEditorPart part) {
        return (IEditorReference) ((PartSite) part.getSite()).getPane().getPartReference();
    }
```

In eclipse 4.2 I get an error at `getPane()`.
With what should it be replaced?

Comment: What are you using this piece of code for?

Comment: What error are you getting?  Full stack trace would be nice.

Comment: its compilation error, this method doesn't exists in 4.2 anymore.

Comment: PartSite was an internal implementation class.  It was not part of the API nor guaranteed to be there in 4.2.  As was asked, what was the reference actually being used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just do `((PartSite) part.getSite()).getPartReference();`